# Sort an array by string length within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I have a problem that wants me to take an array of words, and return them in an array from smallest to largest word.  This has to be done in a function.  I have a simple form of it that is returning the results I desire:

```
//arr = ["Beg", "Life", "I", "To"]
//arr.sort(function(a, b){
//  return a.length - b.length;
//});
```

But I need to put it into a function.  Here is what I have thus far with that part:

```
function sortByLength (array) {
    array.sort(function(a, b){
       return a.length - b.length;
    });
}
sortByLength(["Telescopes", "Glasses", "Eyes", "Monocles"]);
```

I am not looking for the answer.  Just some advice as to what I am doing wrong.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You just need to add a return statement to your function so that it returns the sorted array :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
function sortByLength (array) {
   return array.sort((x,y) => x.length - y.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `sortByLength` function, you're not returning anything, so it's undefined. Consider putting a `return` just before the `array.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah well just *return* the array. But as sorting sorts the passed array, it might be good to use *.slice* for copying it. Boiled down to an arrow func:

```
const sortByLength = arr => arr.slice().sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length);
```

Or if you wanna do that faster ( maybe ) with a length table:

```
const sortByLength = arr => 
  arr.reduce((table,s)=> ( 
    (table[s.length] || (table[s.length] = [])).push(s), table), 
    []
  ).reduce((result, tablerow) => 
    result.concat(tablerow),
    []
);
```

Yup that ugly thing [works](http://jsbin.com/daxuworafa/edit?console) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually returning your value, you just need a return statement inside your `sortByLength` function:

```js
function sortByLength(array) {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  });
}

console.log(sortByLength(["Telescopes", "Glasses", "Eyes", "Monocles"]));
```

**Edit**: if you don't want to modify the original array, just add a `slice()` into the function and it will return a new array:

```
function sortByLength(array) {
  return array.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  });
}

var arrayOne = ["Telescopes", "Glasses", "Eyes", "Monocles"];
var arrayTwo = sortByLength(arrayOne);
```